# .NET - Is it possible to write a DataTable directly to a SQL Database?

Tags: .net, sql

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
Dim Conn as new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

MyDataTable.WriteToDB(Conn, "New Table")
```

Are there any shortcuts like this built into .NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to start with the [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) class. It was pretty much designed to do exactly this.